# CSS: Vertical centering and overflow content

Tags: css, layout

I'm using the verticle centering code from http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

The problem is that when the content gets longer, it will get out of box rathern than break the line.

[image]

```
<div class="reach align-middle">
  <div class="align-block">
    <div>block3</div>
    <div>Long Description Long DescriptionLong DescriptionLong DescriptionLong Description</div>
  </div>
</div>

.reach{
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.align-middle:before{
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
}

.align-middle:before, .align-middle .align-block {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

UPDATE:
It fails to break line in Firefox but well in chrome. That's weird.

Comment: breaks fine for me in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/Cfya7/

Comment: @agconti It works in Chrome, but fails at firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the significant whitespace in html 5.

Check out the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cfya7/4/)

```
.align-middle {
    font-size: 0;
}

.align-block {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Basically, we need to set font-size to 0 on the parent, so the whitespace doesn't take up any space. Then set it back to a sane size on the child...

Oh, and we no longer need the negative margin-left...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be easy to guess on a Fiddle. Hope this could help.

```
.align-middle:before, .align-middle .align-block {
  margin:0 auto;
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
```